# Differences between window.location = MVC File() and $.ajax's success( window.location = result )?

Tags: javascript, ajax, window.location

In my mind these two bits of code should work the same:

```
window.location = "../PlanView/ExportAsPDF";

$.ajax({
    url: '../PlanView/ExportAsPDF',
    data: { },
    success: function (stream) { window.location = stream; }
});
```

The former bit of code triggers a .PDF file download for the user. The second one does not -- I have a weird request pending in my browser's network traffic.

Could someone highlight the key differences here that I should be aware of?

More in-depth explanation:

I need to pass more data to my server than is allowed in a URL. As such, I need to POST to the server instead of GET.  I cannot use the former code because I cannot shove that much information into a URL -- the server will respond with 414.

I would like to replicate the functionality of the former bit of code with the latter.

```
public ActionResult ExportAsPDF(string dataURL)
{
    Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4.Rotate(), 15, 15, 30, 65); 

    byte[] buffer = new byte[0];
    using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, memoryStream);

        document.Open();
        document.Add(new Paragraph("First PDF file"));
        document.Close();
        buffer = memoryStream.ToArray();
    }

    return File(buffer, "application/pdf", "PlanView.pdf");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first one is different from the second because the first one tells the browser to display the file and the second one does not. Simply because "stream" won't be "../PlanView/ExportAsPDF".

Also there's no need for this ajax request if you just want to direct the browser to the file. Also the latter if it at all works, would give you what - binary contents of the PDF file? Frankly I wouldn't know how to handle that :)

You should also have "dataType" not "datatype" in your ajax attributes if you expect to get JSON back (which of course you won't get).

UPDATE:

Even this should work:

```
$.ajax({
url: '../PlanView/ExportAsPDF',
method : 'POST',
data: { },
dataType: 'json',
success: function (stream) { window.location = '../PlanView/ExportAsPDF'; }
});
```

Comment: Well, how do I tell the browser to display the file? In my actual implementation I am using a POST not a GET -- so I have to use the latter code and not the former. Yet, my downloads do not trigger when using the latter -- only the former.

Comment: The browser needs an URL to display a file. Now how you serve that file under that URL is another story... you can either have a regular file or you could send the contents via some backend code (written in PHP, Python or whatever) what you seem to want to do. For sure the latter (ajax request) won't work though unless what you get back is an URL of the file. Then you could do what you're doing, i.e. window.location = URL. So for example make your POST request and have it return the URL of the file, then direct browser to that URL...

Comment: Ok, so referring to your update, what are the contents of "stream" variable, i.e. what does your server return?

Comment: I edited into my original post the File object returned by my MVC ActionResult method.

Comment: So as I mentioned, you're trying to assing binary stream to window.location, not to mention that you told jQuery you expect to get  'application/json' back and you send 'application/pdf'. This won't work. Why not return the path to the "PlanView.pdf" instead of the contents of that file?

Comment: I guess I am just not making the leap for why, when passing small amounts of data to/from the server, it is possible to trigger a download without creating a 'hard' copy of the file on the server. Are you saying that any time a user wishes to download a file from the server via a POST request, that the server will lose disk space hosting the file in order to serve it to the user? Seems quirky...

Comment: No, I'm not considering how the file is served on the server. I'm just saying that for the browser to download it you need the URL. It can be either the URL to the file, e.g. "example.com/file.pdf" or the URL of something that will return the contents, e.g. "example.com/get_me_the_pdf_dynamically_action". Another thing is that you probably have the file on the server anyway? Then serving the file via your application (rather than directly via the webserver) has really bad performance implications...

Comment: Okay. It all makes sense now, I understand what I need to do tomorrow morning. :) For reference -- I don't have any of the data server side. I am exporting an HTML5 canvas as a PDF by converting it to a base64 string, passing that string to the server, reconstructing the image, shoving the image into a pdf, passing the pdf back to the client for download.